# Connect SnapLogic to Google Cloud SQL Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I have a SnapLogic pipeline that returns tabular data. I'm trying to write the data to a Cloud SQL postgres instance. However, the Postgres Snap only provides space for a username/password. I've download a service account key for connecting to the database from my laptop but I can't see how I can upload the key and connect from my pipeline. I found [this page](https://docs-snaplogic.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/1449033775/Adding+the+SnapLogic+Platform+to+your+Allowlist) in the SnapLogic documentation about whitelisting their IP's but I'm not clear how to implement this to allow access to Cloud SQL.

Has anyone done this successfully?